# Li-ion built-in vs external protection

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, over-voltage-protection

Many Lithium Ion batteries have an internal chip (a protection circuit I guess).
Are External protection circuit (like the TP4056) really necessary due to internal chip?
I can't find the answer on internet, everybody tells to use a protection but I never understood if the internal chip can act as protection without another circuit?

Comment: Welcome :-) Regarding: "*Are External protection circuit (like the TP4056) [...]*" Just for clarification, a TP4056 is not an external protection chip. It is only a Li-ion charger. *Some* Ebay/Aliexpress etc. modules built around the TP4056 charger, also include over-and under-voltage and current protection devices - but not all TP4056-based modules contain those protection devices. Those which do contain them can usually be identified by the extra 2 ICs on the PCB, in addition to the TP4056.

Comment: @SamGibson and OP: The DW01A and 8205 pair usualyl act as the "protection" for over voltage (disconnects charger ground to battery's ground) and over current (disconnect output ground to battery's ground) and short circuit (same as overcurrent). These are the 2 extra IC's which are present on most "tp4056" boards. You can incorporate these 2 ICs into your design **without** a tp4056 if you want just the protection - in the same way you can use just a TP4056 IC without the dw01A and 8205 if you just want to charge and dont want the extra protections - i.e. for a DIY LiIon charger with no load.

Comment: Would those who consider this question unclear please advise why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many but not all LiIon cells have internal protection circuitry. This is intended to protect the cell against gross abuse and is not intended for protection in normal operation.

The TP4056 is a battery charging IC and does NOT have any battery discharge protection provision, BUT it is common for charging boards using the TP4056 to also incorporate additional undervoltage discharge protection circuitry.The TP4056 associated low voltage  cutoff circuitry will usually function above the voltage that an in-cell circuit operates at. For this task the cell BMS is redundant as long as the TP4056 circuit works correctly. In the case of failure the in-cell BMs acts as a backup.

However, in-cell protection usually also provides useful safety features that the TP4056 PCBA does not provide. Typically this includes over voltage protection (for when charging ICs fail) and a gross overcurrent fuse that fails permanently open if very large discharge current are drawn. The latter is useful in the case o major faults that may otherwise result in f laming destruction of the associated device.